# Alternative to Event layer plugin for QGIS > 2.8?

Tags: qgis, offset, linear-referencing

It appears to me and from another post that the qgis "Event layer" plugin is not fully functional in versions above 2.8.

Trials using versions 2.14 & 2.18 failed to generate a Point memory layer. The Line generation feature did function properly.

Our county road system has been processed using the LRS plugin with export to a measured LINESTRINGM. Many of our roadside features such as sign inventory includes an attribute field for left or right offset distance.  The "Event layer" plugin is the only one I've found which travels a variable measured distance along centerline then will apply a left or right offset distance to a feature.  Our sign crew then runs qgis with gps enabled to field check database accuracy. That is why the left right offset is important to us.  Hopefully screenshot below helps clarifies this.

I would like to update to newer versions of QGIS, does anyone have a substitute method I might try?

I tried running multiple versions of qgis on one computer. I found it cumbersome, and I don't believe a viable option for our road crews.

[image]